# what does IE like about the xmlhttprequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have the following code working in all browsers now but IE8..  i read that if i used the xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); line it should work for IE but i'm not sure..anyone have experience in getting this to work with ie8

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {
 xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
 {
 xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
} 

var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("nhl_standings_xml.xml");
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("nhlall");
```

Comment: IE8 (and IE7) [supports XMLHttpRequest natively](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc534581%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). What exactly "is not working"? I am going to guess it's the use of of a synchronous request (or lack of using a library), but who knows.

Comment: C'mon, you don't need jQuery just to do a simple AJAX request. jQuery is making people unable to understand the fundamental processes of JavaScript...

Comment: the variables are coming back undefined ..  working in all other browsers.. i have the files locally hosted on apache .. and jquery or not shouldnt it still be working in theory?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the code looks okay. Have you tried an [Asynchronous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O) request? When you have `xhttp.open("GET", dname, false);`, it's synchronous. Change that `false` to a `true`, and you're asynchronous. Also, you variable `xhttp` isn't properly declared (correct me if I'm wrong. Being a Python coder, I can't tell half of the time).

Try this code:

```
function loadXML(url)
{
  var xmlHttp;

  try
  {
    // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } catch (e) {
    // Internet Explorer
    try
    {
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
      try
      {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (e) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
    {
      return xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
  }

  xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}

var xmlDoc = loadXML("nhl_standings_xml.xml");
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("nhlall");
```

Comment: the variables are declared okay. . you don't HAVE to put var in front, but i did.. and changed the false to true.. still same result..  can you explain what changing it from synchronous to asyncronous does?

Comment: Quoted from some random place: Requests made with sync mode should be avoided. These requests will cause the browser to lock up for the user until the request returns. In cases where the server is busy and the response takes a while, the user's browser (and maybe OS) will not allow anything else to be done. In cases where a response is never properly received, the browser may continue to block until the request is timed out.

Comment: Okay, I think I know what the problem is. Your function isn't waiting for a `200` message (success = 200). I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you this MINIMAL ajax engine.

http://pastebin.com/uXJe9hVC

an example of usuage

ajax POST request

```
Ajax.call('GET','http://localhost/index.php',function(data) {
{
 //doing stuff with the data response
},'ASD');
```

call arguments: URL,callback,POST

this is so easy.

Comment: can you tell me where i put the url to xml page in that code? and also what variable is equal to xmlDoc from above?

Comment: isnt that the same thing i had above tho?  sorry.. i know it is easy but i cant figure it out.. what is different about that code than the one i posted originally?

Comment: every browsers seems to be working correctly when ran on apache..  but ie8 and the previous versions are still hiccuping. .  i tried to refresh caches and everything

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a request starter:

```
  if      (window.XMLHttpRequest) return new window.XMLHttpRequest();
  else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
     // the many versions of IE's XML fetchers
     var AXOs = [
        'MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0',
        'MSXML2.XMLHTTP.5.0',
        'MSXML2.XMLHTTP.4.0',
        'MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0',
        'MSXML2.XMLHTTP',
        'Microsoft.XMLHTTP',
        'MSXML.XMLHTTP'
     ];
     for (var i = 0; i < AXOs.length; i++) {
        try     { return new ActiveXObject(AXOs[i]); }
        catch() { continue; }
     }
     return null;
  }
```

The order above should be the correct best-to-worse order, BTW.